# Why is there a non-negative gradient vector at the unique maximum?

Tags: optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HIm3Z0L90Co) lecture on KKT conditions and on the 14:05 mark he denotes the $x^*$ as the optimal solution to the problem with the curve shown in green. The feasibility region is covered in shades and only the point $x^*$ is the one that maximizes $f$.

He then proceeds to draw the gradient vector at the point $x^*$ to denote the direction of steepest ascent and makes the gradient vector equal to the linear combination of the constraint gradients  using Lagrange multipliers. Now, as far as I know, the gradient vector at any local optima is zero (correct me if I am wrong). Is there something I am missing, or is it a perspective issue?

Comment: How does that correlate to the fact that gradients become zero at optimal points? Consider a non-linear case.

Comment: If the top is not flat then the maximum height can be anywhere. Elaborate a little further?

Comment: Take a look at [this image](https://www.math24.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/global-extrema-case1.svg). Finding where the derivative vanishes only allows you to find the local minimum and maximum. Yet, the global minimum and maximum are attained at the boundary.